# python-docx to generate document with MySQL data

Tags: python, mysql, django, vba, python-docx

I have a Django application working with MySQL and I need to generate a docx document with SQL data.I am thinking about using python-docx. The document I need to generate can be very large, about hundreds of pages, and it will contain lots of images, tables, etc. Has anyone here used python-docx? Any suggestion about its efficiency with large files? How limited is in order to carry out specific tasks as making a table of contents or embedding a file?

The other option would be to use VBA instead querying the data to the database and filling the docx document.

Any tips or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, unless the document needs to be user-editable, a LaTex-based solution will probably be better. If the document is intended to be user-editable, VBA is possibly a better option since it could give you native support for creating word `.docx` documents. Anyway, you will almost invariably have to loop through your objects to get data that needs to be inserted between tags. That can be tedious if you have a lot of fields or a lot of variations in different output files. You could check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22950093/possible-to-insert-page-in-word-document-with-python-docx?rq=1) answer, it involves xml. Slightly more detail on the nature and need of the document would probably help.

cheers